# Lazy Initialization with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

I´m getting a lazy initialization exception. A have a controller method with the annotation @Transactional, it invokes a service method ( it not has the @Transactional annotation), and finally inside that method I invoke another spring component (it checks if the user has the proper role).

In the project I used the @Transactional and i have no problems. But in this case i have the lazy initialization exception.

Am I missing something?

Here is the code:

and here is the method that is first executed. It has the @Transactional annotation

```
@Transactional
    public CompanyForm edit(){
        CompanyForm form = new CompanyForm();
        Company company = companyService.findMainOne(getLoggedUser());
        if (company != null) {
            if (company != null)
                modelMapper.map(company, form);
        }
        return form;
    }
```

This is the method in a service where the code is called

```
@Autowired
    private UserVisitorHasBussinessRole hasBussinessRole;

@Override
    public Company findMainOne(User user) {
        if (user == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("the user can not be null");
        user.accept(hasBussinessRole);
        List<Company> companies = this.companyRepository.findOwnedBy(user
                .getId());
        if (companies != null && companies.size() > 0)
            return companies.get(0);
        return null;
    }
```

This component checks if the user has the proper role. This is where i got the exception

```
@Component
public class UserVisitorHasBussinessRole implements UserVisitor {

    @Autowired
    private Messages messages;

    @Override
    public void visit(SystemUser user) {
        if(user == null || user.getUserRoles() == null || user.getUserRoles().isEmpty())
        {
            String message = messages.get("hasBussinesRoleVisitor.noRole");
            throw new RuntimeException(message);
        }
        Boolean hasRole = false;
        for (UserRole role : user.getUserRoles()) {
            if(role instanceof UserRoleBusiness){
                hasRole = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!hasRole)
        {
            String message = messages.get("hasBussinesRoleVisitor.noRole");
            throw new RuntimeException(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(SocialUser user) {
        String message = messages.get("hasBussinesRoleVisitor.noRole");
        throw new RuntimeException(message);
    }

}
```

This is where the exception is thrown

```
user.getUserRoles().isEmpty()
```

The entity:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "BU")
public class SystemUser extends User {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3845147625976106863L;

    // for joing the tables (many-to-many)
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = UserRole.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "systemUser_userRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "system_user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_Id") })
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;

    /**
     * the list of user roles
     * @return the user roles
     */
    public List<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    /***
     * set the list of user roles
     * @param userRoles the user roles
     */
    public void setUserRoles(List<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at ar.com.held.model.user.User.accept(Unknown Source)
    at ar.com.held.service.implementation.CompanyServiceImpl.findMainOne(Unknown Source)
    at ar.com.held.service.implementation.CompanyServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d0027e0c.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at ar.com.held.service.implementation.CompanyServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b15b3940_2.findMainOne(<generated>)
    at ar.com.held.controller.CompanyFlowController.edit(CompanyFlowController.java:28)
    at ar.com.held.controller.CompanyFlowController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c3823c4.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at ar.com.held.controller.CompanyFlowController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5b3921c7_2.edit(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:109)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:534)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:225)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ar.com.held.model.user.SystemUser.userRoles, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.isEmpty(PersistentBag.java:249)
    at ar.com.held.service.implementation.visitor.UserVisitorHasBussinessRole.visit(Unknown Source)
    ... 100 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when a lazy initialized object is read when the original transaction is already completed. In other words, when you return something from a method with @Transactional annotation all objects must be initialized (no way to access lazy objects after returning from the method). So use lazy="false" in this case to resolve the issue (or force lazy initialization inside the method).

Comment: Thanks! But how can i force lazy initialization inside the method? calling user.getUserRoles().size()?

Comment: Iterate through all connected items and call any getter except getId() which is already loaded. I would suggest to change hibernate mapping though, to make it lazy="false"

Comment: Well, i solved it. I have to use @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)

Answer (score 4):

I solved using @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)

here is the code:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = UserRole.class)
@JoinTable(name = "systemUser_userRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "system_user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_Id") })
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<UserRole> userRoles;
```

It is not the best solution but it works. The problem is that LazyCollection annotation is a Hibernate annotation and not a jpa one.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Transactional` to `findMainOne` and `visit(SystemUser)` so they both participate in the same transaction, thus giving them access to the session/entity-manager for lazily-loading related components. Or you can load those components that might be needed before calling `findMainOne`.